# How do I make rich:dataGrid responsive?

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap, datagrid, responsive-design, richfaces

I'm looking for a way to make a dataGrid provided by richfaces responsive.
Meaning, the grid scales based on the size of the device screen.

I've taken a look at Richfaces Bootstrap : http://planet.jboss.org/post/richfaces_bootstrap
but they recommend not to use it in any production code since it is still under development. Tags and attributes are subject to change at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to overwrite the default CSS. [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/appe-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters-richdataGrid) is the list of classes that make up a dataGrid.

The responsivness is achieved by queries like this:

```
@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:979px) {
    /* styles for the given width range */
}
```

You shouldn't use the Bootstrap components but you can use the CSS. However the dataGrid is a table and those don't scale very well.

Comment: Is there a reason I shouldn't use bootstrap components?

Comment: It hasn't been touched in a while and as we're heading to RF 5 some stuff might not be working properly.